# Best method to transfer/clone large MySQL databases to another server

Tags: mysql, backup

I am running a web application within a shared hosting environment which uses a MYSQL database which is about 3GB large.

For testing purposes I have setup a XAMPP environment on my local macOS machine. To copy the online DB to my local machine I used `mysqldump` on the server and than directly imported the dump file to `mysql`:

```
// Server
$ mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u dbUser -p'dbPass' --extended-insert dbName > dbDump.sql

// Local machine
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.3 -u dbUser -p'dbPass' dbName < dbDump.sql
```

The only optimization here is the use of `extended-insert`. However the import takes about **10 hours**!

After some searching I found that disabling foreign constraint checks during the import should speed up the process. So I added the following line at the begining of the dump file:

```
// dbDump.sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
...
```

However this did not make any significant difference... The import now took about 8 hours. Faster but still pretty long.

**Why does it take so much time to import the data? Is there a better/faster way to do this?**

The server is not the fastest (shared hosting...) but it takes just about 2 minutes to export/dump the data. That exporting is faster than importing (no syntax checks, no parsing, just writing...) is not surprising but 300 times faster (10 hours vs. 2 minutes)? This is a huge difference...

Isn't there any other solution that would be faster? Copy the binary DB file instead, for example? Anything would be better than using a text file as transfer medium.

This is not just about transferring the data to another machine for testing purposes. I also create daily backups of the database. If it would be necessary to restore the DB it would be pretty bad if the site is down for 10 hours...